# Visualize the files generated by the tensor-board after training

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I activated the tensor-board option during training to view the metrics and learning during training. It created a directory called “runs (default)” and placed the files there. The files look like this:

```
events.out.tfevents.1590963894.moissan.17321.0
```

I have tried viewing the content of the file, but it’s a binary file…

Please can anyone help me with how to view the files generated when you activate the tensor-board option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To view these files, you need to install tensorboard: https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/get_started

Once tensorboard is installed, open a terminal window and run via

```
tensorboard --logdir=runs\ (default)
```

If using standard options, you will then be able to view by opening `http://127.0.0.1:6006/` in your web browser.

Comment: I saved these files after training my questions can I open it after training or it must be during the training

Comment: You can view them after training.

Comment: sorry because I am not an expert in the tensor board I opened tensor board in my browser how can the open this file

Comment: If you start tensorboard using the command in my answer (with the folder containing your file as --logdir argument), it should automatically open your file.

Comment: tensorboard --logdir= "C:\Users\Nabihovich\Desktop\logs"  is this correct?

Comment: I am not on Windows so not sure - you can try that or without quotes

Comment: okay, thanks for help another clarification do I need to put the name of the file in the path tensorboard --logdir= "C:\Users\Nabihovich\Desktop\logs\filename

Comment: You don’t need the filename

Comment: Is there a GUI, so we just double click on the event file?